# Idiomatic Ruby FizzBuzz

Tags: beginner, ruby, fizzbuzz

Can anyone offer any criticism on the following at a simple FizzBuzz in terms of Ruby idioms or otherwise?

```
class FizzBuzz

  def initialize(fizz = 'Fizz', buzz = 'Buzz')
    @fizz = fizz
    @buzz = buzz
  end

  def is_number_divisible_by?(number, divisor)
    number % divisor == 0
  end

  def get_text(number)
    fizz_buzz_text = ''
    if is_number_divisible_by?(number, 3)
      fizz_buzz_text += @fizz
    end
    if is_number_divisible_by?(number, 5)
      fizz_buzz_text += @buzz
    end
    return fizz_buzz_text
  end

end

fb = FizzBuzz.new
(1...101).each do |i|
  fb_text = fb.get_text(i)
  puts fb_text.empty? ? i : fb_text
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off: If you want a range that goes from 1 to x, inclusive, write `(1..x)`, not `(1...x+1)`.

Second, if it's the last line executed in a method, it's automatically returned -- so in `get_text`, you don't need `return` in the last line, just the actual code.

Also, `get_text` should return the text to be printed, not what it might be. Move the empty check (`fb_text.empty ? i : fb_text`) to `get_text` instead of having it at the `puts` call. See the code at the end for clarification.

`if` statements with just one line should be expressions at the end. Again, see the modified code for what I mean.

Methods defined in a class are generally talking about the object they're run on. I'd pull `is_number_divisible_by?` out of the class and dropping it at the beginning of your code instead, and renaming it to something like `divisible_by?` instead (since it's shorter and carries the same information).

Aside from that (and an odd extra newline at the beginning of your class definition), it looks good! Here's your code with these suggestions:

```
def divisible_by?(number, divisor)
  number % divisor == 0
end

class FizzBuzz
  def initialize(fizz = 'Fizz', buzz = 'Buzz')
    @fizz = fizz
    @buzz = buzz
  end

  def get_text(number)
    fizz_buzz_text = ''
    fizz_buzz_text += @fizz if divisible_by? number, 3
    fizz_buzz_text += @buzz if divisible_by? number, 5
    fizz_buzz_text.empty? ? number : fizz_buzz_text
  end

end

fb = FizzBuzz.new
(1..100).each do |i|
  puts fb.get_text i
end
```

Note: Personally, I wouldn't do this in an OOP way. Ruby is much more oriented towards functional programming, though of course OOP is perfectly valid; besides, functional is a bit simpler. My preferred way to do it would be something like this:

```
(1..100).each do |num|
  output = ''
  output += 'Fizz' if num % 3 == 0
  output += 'Buzz' if num % 5 == 0
  puts output.empty? ? num : output
end
```

Answer (score -1):

QPaysTaxes has a lot of great points, but one thing that stands out is that you are asking for the "Idiomatic" way of doing things in ruby. For fizzbuzz, that would involve a hash mapping numbers to words so you could easily and arbitrarily extend it.  I would rewrite QPaysTaxes `get_text` function as such to get more idiomatic ruby:

```
# in class FizzBuzz
TEXT = {
  3 => "Fizz",
  5 => "Buzz",
  # 7 => "Jazz",
  # 11 => "Guzz",
} # or set this dynamically during initialization, whatever

def get_text(number)
  fizz_buzz_text = TEXT.inject("") do |str, rule|
    number % rule[0] == 0 ? str + rule[1] : str 
  end

  fizz_buzz_text.empty? ? number : fizz_buzz_text 
end
```

Now you can uncomment those extra rules or throw your own in with ease. If the method for determining replacement or not changes from being `num divisible by rule` to `((num * 6) + 4) is divisible by rule`, you only need to change a single location instead of once per rule. (This practice is called DRY, or "Don't Repeat Yourself".)

I can explain the code further if you want, just leave a comment below.

Comment: I'm almost certain that you should be using `''` for strings wherever possible, like in `inject("")`. Could be wrong on that, though.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Style guide says you can use either, as long as you remain consistent (which I did not, I fixed it).

Comment: I dont think this makes the code more idiomatic?  What you have done is tried to make it more extensible and also isnt it breaking the YAGNI principle?  fizz_buzz becomes less relevant here for names now also - since you have tried to make it more general purpose anyway?

Comment: Fizz buzz is the general name of this problem, it doesn't matter what the specific text is. And whether or not you'll need it is on a case by case basis. Obviously for just FizzBuzz you do not, but the purpose of learning FizzBuzz is so that you can apply it to real world problems, where you are *far* more likely to need to keep things extensible.